# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

this is my code . It adding some records. But at some point giving me error.

```
foreach($data as $obj){

  if($obj && $obj->stateId && $obj->countryId) {
     MasterCity::create(array(
        'name' => $obj->name,
        'state_id' => $obj->stateId,
        'country_id' => $obj->countryId
    ));
  }
}
```

I am getting 2 errors:

```
 C:\ashish\backend\laravel-backend\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:129
      Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blue_rickshaw`.`mast
er_cities`, CONSTRAINT `master_cities_state_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES `master_states` (`id`))")

  2   C:\ashish\backend\laravel-backend\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:127
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blue_rickshaw`.`master_cities`, CONSTRAIN
T `master_cities_state_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES `master_states` (`id`))")
```

Comment: are you updating `master_cities.state_id` with value that does not exist in `master_states.id` ?

Comment: I am adding record in master_cities table. state_id is foriegn key of master_states table.

Comment: yes, but value that you assigning to the `master_cities.state_id` via `$obj->stateId` must exist in `master_states` table. Does it?

Comment: @JuscPranskaitis I think. that i want to solve... means how can i handle this situation

Comment: As it throws you an error `I think` that `$obj->stateId` does not exist in `master_states`. You can solve this by assigning `$obj->stateId` that exists in `master_states`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reference a state_id that doesn't exist.

Practically, you need to insert a record in the parent table BEFORE you can reference it

Comment: This is not a 'code' issue, you have to understand what Referential integrity is if you want to work with relational databases. you can read on it here :https://database.guide/what-is-referential-integrity/#:~:text=Referential%20integrity%20refers%20to%20the,%E2%80%93%20or%20parent%20%E2%80%93%20table).